# All product pair sum in range [L, R]

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am looking for a direct formula to calculate, *sum of all possible product pairs* from $[L, R]$, for instance, if $L = 3$ and $R = 6$, then,

$$ sum = 3*(4+5+6) + 4*(5+6) + 5*6$$

I tried to make an $O(n)$ solution for this, and I came up with: let $S$ be sum of all numbers in range $[L, R]$, then,

$$res = \sum_{i=L}^R{(S := S - i) * i}$$

where $:=$ denotes in-place assignment. But, this one isn't efficient for $1 \lt L \lt R \lt 10^9$.

So, is there any direct formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: given the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$ $$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ca)$$
and the expansion of $(a+b+c+d)^2$ $$(a+b+c+d)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$
Can you find a more general formula?

Answer (score 1):

The sum from L to R is $S=(R-L+1)(R+L/2)$. All pairs sum to $S*S$. The sum for squares up to $n$ is $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ . Removing the pairs $(L,L)$,...$(R,R)$ is $S*S- R(R+1)(2R+1)/6+L(L+1)(2L+1)/6$. Now divide the entire thing by 2 to get rid of duplicates.